# Pagination only returning first page values

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

For the past 2 days I've been looking for a pagination script of sorts, and I found this one which I'm starting to implement on my website.

The code is the following:

```
<?php 
    if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
    { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    } 
   $data = mysqli_query($lig,"SELECT * FROM requisicao") or die("data"); 
   $rows = mysqli_num_rows($data); 
   $page_rows = 5; 
   $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 
   if ($pagenum < 1) 
   { 
         $pagenum = 1; 
   } 
   elseif ($pagenum > $last) 
   { 
       $pagenum = $last; 
   } 
   $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

   $data_p = mysqli_query($lig,"SELECT * FROM requisicao $max") or die("data_p"); 
   while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $data_p )) 
   { 
   ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php print $info['id_requisicao']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php print $info['username']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php print $info['nome_servico']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php print $info['data_requisicao']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php print $info['estado_requisicao']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php print $info['prioridade']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php print $info['total']; ?> </td>
       <td align="center">+</td>
   <tr>
   <?php
   } 
   ?>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <?php
   if ($pagenum == 1) 
   {
   } 
   else 
   {
       echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-Início</a> ";
       echo " ";
       $previous = $pagenum-1;
       echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Anterior</a> ";
   } 
   echo " ---- ";
   if ($pagenum == $last) 
   {
   } 
   else {
       $next = $pagenum+1;
       echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Seguinte -></a> ";
       echo " ";
       echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Última ->></a> ";
   } 
   ?>
```

I'm getting the first 5 rows out of it, but when I press Seguinte (which is Next) it changes the link (TO PAGE 2) but it doesn't change the values that get outputed. Basically, it always shows page 1.

I've also looked into several similar questions but I haven't found solutions that fix my problem.

Thanks in advance, and my apologies if this is a simple problem and I'm just overlooking things :s

Comment: So I'm guessing that $pagenum always is 1 even though it looks like you change pages?

Comment: Use COUNT(*) for counting the rows, it's so much faster.

Comment: @tony.gustafsson so... select COUNT(*) from table? isn't that pretty much the same, though?

Comment: No, it just counts the rows, it does not actually fetch them.

Comment: Try to echo $max for debugging and you will see if your query is correct

Comment: @steven thanks for the tip. indeed, the query wasn't being updated. max kept being limit 0,5

Comment: so echo $pagenum an you will see that it is always 1 like @tony.gustafsson metioned. We cannot see any `$pagenum = (int)$_GET['pagenum'];` so it seems to be the case that `if(!isset($pagenum))` is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$pagenum` will be initialized as 1, anyway.

Instead of:

```
if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
{ 
    $pagenum = 1; 
}
```

Try writing this:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['pagenum']) || !is_int($_REQUEST['pagenum'])) 
{ 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else {
    $pagenum = (int)$_REQUEST['pagenum'];
}
```

You may find some more info handling HTTP Request variables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: casting pagenum as (int) would be nice because of not using any prepare statements.

Comment: good sir, I'm grateful for your help! I've invested 2 days into the pagination and I finnaly found peace.

Comment: @steven, agreed. thanks for the remark. I added an int check too.